# STM32F0 (master) writing multiple bytes by I2C to MCP4728 (slave) using StdPeriphLibrary

Tags: stm32, i2c, dac, stm32f0

void I2C_Config(void) {
    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C_InitStructure;

```
I2C_StructInit(&I2C_InitStructure);
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Timing = (PRESC << 28) | (SCLDEL << 20)
        | (SDADEL << 16) | (SCLH << 8) | SCLL;      // 100kHz
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;      // I2C mode
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable; // enable acknowledge when reading (can be changed later on)
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit; // set address length to 7 bit addresses
I2C_Init(I2C_PERIPH, &I2C_InitStructure);       // init I2C peripheral
I2C_Cmd(I2C_PERIPH, ENABLE);
```

}

void I2C_HW_tx(uint8_t i2cAddr, uint8_t *dataTx, uint8_t length,
        uint8_t stopOrNotWhenSent) {

```
if (stopOrNotWhenSent == STOP_WHEN_SENT) {
    I2C_TransferHandling(I2C_PERIPH, i2cAddr, 1, I2C_Reload_Mode,
    I2C_Generate_Start_Write);
    PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 1\n");
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXIS) == RESET)
        ;
    PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 2\n");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        I2C_SendData(I2C_PERIPH, *(dataTx + i));
        while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TCR) == RESET)
            ;
        PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 3\n");
    }
    I2C_AutoEndCmd(I2C_PERIPH, ENABLE);
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXIS) == RESET)
        ;
    I2C_SendData(I2C_PERIPH, *(dataTx + length - 1));
    I2C_ReloadCmd(I2C_PERIPH, DISABLE);
} else {
    I2C_TransferHandling(I2C_PERIPH, i2cAddr, length, I2C_SoftEnd_Mode,
    I2C_Generate_Start_Write);
    PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 1\n");
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXIS) == RESET)
        ;
    PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 2\n");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        I2C_SendData(I2C_PERIPH, *(dataTx + i));
        while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TC) == RESET)
            ;
        PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 3\n");
    }
}
if (stopOrNotWhenSent == STOP_WHEN_SENT) {
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_STOPF) == RESET)
        ;
    I2C_ClearFlag(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_STOPF);
}
PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 4\n");
```

}

void I2C_HW_rx(uint8_t i2cAddr, uint8_t *dataRx, uint8_t length) {

```
PRINTF("\nI2C_rx - 1\n");
I2C_TransferHandling(I2C_PERIPH, i2cAddr, length, I2C_AutoEnd_Mode,
I2C_Generate_Start_Read);

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET)
        ;
    PRINTF("\nI2C_rx - 2\n");
    *(dataRx + i) = I2C_ReceiveData(I2C_PERIPH);
}
while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_STOPF) == RESET)
    ;
PRINTF("\nI2C_rx - 3\n");
I2C_ClearFlag(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_STOPF);
```

}

I read bytes from MCP4728 using I2C_HW_rx with success.
The problem is with I2C_HW_tx - it halts when trying to send:

```
uint8_t dataTx[8];
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    *(dataTx + i * 2) =
            FASTWRITE
                    | (((channelData->powerMode << 4)
                            | (channelData->dacValue >> 8)) & 0x3F);
    *(dataTx + i * 2 + 1) = channelData->dacValue & 0xFF;
    if (i < 3) {
        channelData++;
    }
}
I2C_HW_tx(DEVICE_CODE | (mcp4728WholeData[mcp4728Id].currI2CAddr << 1),
        dataTx, 8, STOP_WHEN_SENT);
```

}

So my question to You - how to send multiple bytes by STM32F0 (master) to I2C bus, using StdPeriphLibrary? I was searching in Google, but the few examples with StdPeriphLibrary for STM32F0 are with sending I2Caddr, register and value (three bytes), but I need to send for example I2Caddr and ten bytes.

Answer (score 1):

OK i managed with this problem - checking of TCR flag in loop was mistake. The working code is below:

void I2C_HW_tx(uint8_t i2cAddr, uint8_t *dataTx, uint8_t length,
        uint8_t stopOrNotWhenSent) {

```
if (stopOrNotWhenSent == STOP_WHEN_SENT) {
    I2C_TransferHandling(I2C_PERIPH, i2cAddr, length,
    I2C_AutoEnd_Mode,
    I2C_Generate_Start_Write);
    //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 1\n");
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXIS) == RESET)
        ;
    //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 2\n");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXE) == RESET)
            ;
        I2C_SendData(I2C_PERIPH, *(dataTx + i));
        //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 3\n");
    }
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_STOPF) == RESET)
        ;
    I2C_ClearFlag(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_STOPF);
} else {
    I2C_TransferHandling(I2C_PERIPH, i2cAddr, length, I2C_SoftEnd_Mode,
    I2C_Generate_Start_Write);
    //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 1\n");
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXIS) == RESET)
        ;
    //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 2\n");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TXE) == RESET)
            ;
        I2C_SendData(I2C_PERIPH, *(dataTx + i));
        //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 3\n");
    }
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_PERIPH, I2C_FLAG_TC) == RESET)
        ;
    //PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 4\n");
}
//PRINTF("\nI2C_tx - 5\n");
```

}

The one thing that I don't know how to do is WriteI2CAddress to MCP4728 slave device (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22187E.pdf - page 42). LDAC line should become low from high state during 8th bit of command. Do you know how to do it using hardware I2C in STM32?